# Pneumatic in linux

Tags: 14.04

i'm student. I'm learning about pneumatic.
In class, computer of school used app FluitSIM to learn. The computer used window 7.
My computer used Ubuntu 14.04 Lts. I need some app like fluitSIM to learn.
I need your help!
Thank so much!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please explain what pneumatic is and what FluitSIM does. We might know of alternatives but we can't help unless you tell us what these things are.

Comment: fluitSIM is simulation system pneumatic.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide links to where we can read about these tools.

Comment: https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=fluidSIM&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=fvEqVITxGoaf8QXBzYIo&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1223&bih=691#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=K6qKKCpCP7u1eM%253A%3BS3ICv5Huze8UzM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fxtronic.org%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2010%252F08%252Ffluidsim-41.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fxtronic.org%252Fdownload%252Ffluidsim-4-simulation-electropneumatic%252F%3B400%3B336

Answer (score 0):

There are tools to do some of the tasks you can do with that VERY special program you are searching for. 
For the CAD part try out Draftsight (search on the internet, it's a free AutoCAD-Clone, .deb-file available) or LibreCAD. Fittings can be downloaded as blocks from the internet. 
3D part Blender. 
Diagrams can be done with some (electrical) circuit programs, which might fit your needs.
Calculation with Calc (LibreOffice).

All this means months of learning. But you won't find a specialised production software for free in the Ubuntu Softwarecenter. So, I would recommend to ask, if you could get the software from your University, or if there is a free student version. Probably you won't even find it cracked on qbittorrent.

If you get the Windows-Version from somewhere try to install it under Wine or Virtual Box on Ubuntu.

Comment: This software didn't do drow CAD. It simulation system pneumatic.

Comment: This software didn't do drow CAD. It simulation system pneumatic.
I asked my teacher but they said "I don't know, you should serch it in internet". I search "wine" in software center, I don't know choose of Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer or Q4Wine or Wine Windows Program Loader or PlayOnLinux to use!

Comment: The basic program is Wine Windows Program Loader. Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer is a metapackage, which installs the most suited WINE-Version and some other stuff. You should install this one. Then rightclick on your .exe-installer and select "install with WINE". The other programs you mentioned are just "better" graphic interfaces to make things easier and to emulate different windows versions. They are for advanced use.